# Force OPAM to reinstall a local git repo

Tags: ocaml, opam

If I have a local Git repo on some branch/commit, is there a *reliable* way to make `opam` install it locally.

These options all work if you have never installed it before:

```
opam install . --yes
opam pin . --yes
```

However if you then add a new commit or switch branch they *sometimes* work, but it just seems to arbitrarily decide that nothing has changed and it won't do anything. Is there any way to force it to recompile and reinstall?

I have tried

```
opam reinstall . --yes
```

and adding `--working-dir`, but `--working-dir` seems to have no effect. In general `opam` is *very* confusing.

Is there something that works sanely like `cargo install --path . --force` for Rust?

Answer (score 0):

Opam behaves oddly but not arbitrarily with respect to a dependency which is pinned to a local directory which is cloned by git.  By default it will only pick up a change if that change has been committed.

The --working-dir option is intended to enable uncommitted changes to be picked up, although I have never used it.  One point about it is that it appears its effect only lasts until the next explicit update, at which point as I understand it you have to reapply the option: but as I say I have never used it.